# MySql + EntityFramework "Backmodel have changed"

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework

I'm working in an App (WinForm + ServiceStack WebServices) and in the AppHost when I try to store some data in a MySql db get this error:[image]

I haven't changed the model. How can I solve this?

Here is MyDbContext

```
public class MySqlContext : System.Data.Entity.DbContext
    {
        public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<LoginModel> LoginModels { get; set; }
        public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<Role> Roles { get; set; }
        public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<Permission> Permissions { get; set; }

        public MySqlContext()
            : base("ConnectionStringName")
        {
            Database.SetInitializer <MySqlContext>(null);

        }


        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {


            modelBuilder.Entity<LoginModel>().HasMany(lm => lm.roles).WithMany(r => r.Users)
                  .Map(
                      m =>
                      {
                          m.MapLeftKey("lm_Id");
                          m.MapRightKey("role_Id");
                          m.ToTable("login_roles");
                      }
                  );

            modelBuilder.Entity<Role>().HasMany(r => r.Permissions).WithMany(p => p.Roles)
                .Map(
                    m =>
                    {
                        m.MapLeftKey("role_id");
                        m.MapRightKey("per_id");
                        m.ToTable("roles_permissions");
                    }
                );



        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
Database.SetInitializer<YourDbContext>(null);
```

In your  DbContext

For Example

```
public class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    public MyDbContext ()
    {
        Database.SetInitializer<MyDbContext >(null);
    }

    public DbSet<Users> Users { get; set; }    
}
```

Comment: Sorry but I don't get the Add(new UserMap()); , please check my update I already add my DbContext.cs @pravprab

Comment: @user1629278 You dont need Add(new UserMap()); . It was there in the example to map entity with table in DB. I removed it to avoid confusion

Comment: Database.SetInitializer <MySqlContext>(null);  Was already there in your DbContext? If it was there my answere is irrelevant :-(